# Identity for classes of plane partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

There are several classes of [plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) in the literature.

Among these, let's look at the enumeration of three of them: the [symmetric (SPP)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.12), [totally symmetric (TSPP)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.12) and [totally symmetric and self-complementary](https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.12) plane partitions (TSSCPP), given respectively, by 
\begin{align*} 
{\tt SPP}_n&=\prod_{i,j=1}^n\frac{i+j+n-1}{i+j+j-2}, \\
{\tt TSPP}_n&=\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}\frac{i+j+n-1}{i+j+j-2}, \\
{\tt TSSCPP}_{2n}&=\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}\frac{i+j+n-1}{i+j+i-1}.
\end{align*}

I know how to prove the below result, algebraically.

> **QUESTION.** Can you provide a combinatorial or conceptual reason for this equality?
>   $${\tt SPP_n=TSPP_n\times TSSCPP_{2n}}.$$

Comment: This is also true at the level of q-analogues.

Comment: That is true, yes.